# Missing include file when using boost

Tags: c++, cmake, boost

I am having an issue using boost, I get the error: "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/algorithm/string.hpp': No such file or directory". I got here following the steps:

1. `git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git`
2. `bootstrap and then .\b2`
3. added boost includes and linked the libs in cmake lists as below:

   ```
   target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE 
   external/boost/libs/algorithm/include)
   target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE external/boost/libs)
   ```
4. Then trying to use the boost string algos:

   ```
   #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
   ```

Could you please help?
I tried using vcpkg and did the below in Cmakelists:

Find and include Boost

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
```

Include Boost headers

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Link against Boost

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE Boost::headers)
```

still I get the same issue:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/algorithm/string.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I am pretty sure I checked the include path and looked correct. Could please someone help?

Comment: You mention everything except the most obvious -- did you actually check to see if that header file exists in `boost/algorithm`?

Comment: Yes I did, it’s there under boost folder in both cases: building from source and using vcpkg

Comment: What `--prefix` did you supply to `./bootstrap.sh`? Is that where you now find the headers and libraries? Did you run `./b2 install`?

Comment: I did not supply any prefix (I thought it was optional) Yes I run ./b2 install. I can see the hpp files under the path I specified in the CMakeLists. I didn’t run anything when using vcpkg

Comment: You use `INTERFACE` keyword, which means that corresponding property is applied for **consumers** of the target, but **not for the target itself**. Instead, use `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE` keyword.

Comment: I used interface because I am building a header only library, I thought we should use interface, if I don’t use add_library(.. INTERFACE) cmake fails with: NO SOURCES given to target

Comment: The first thing you should do is look at the verbose build logs. Extract the actual compilation command and analyze for obvious errors. What `-I` parameters are supplied?

Comment: Please include the _actual _ CMakeLists.txt_ - you have contradictory info in your post (why have `target_include_directories` (with the wrong path) when you already link the `Boost::headers` target)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample `CMakeLists.txt` that I often use when building a library.

```
add_library(xmlhandler xmlhandler.cpp)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS headers)
target_link_libraries(xmlhandler Boost::headers)
```

And then in the `header` file (`xmlhandler.hpp`) I include

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
```

In this example `xmlhandler` is the name of a custom library that uses `<boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>`

Hope this helps.